# Adding extra flags to cache lines with instruction support

Tags: caching, tags, riscv

I would like to include flags in the cache lines of both caches in the current version of the Rocket chip. These flags will be loaded/stored along with the data at a memory address. The lowRISC (http://www.lowrisc.org/) developers have done something similar. However, they access load/store flags and data as separate instructions (i.e. instructions store/load flags and existing instructions to store/load data), and their architecture design was forked from an old version of the rocket-chip, and the rocket-chip source code has changed significantly since then.

In my case, somehow the flags are not getting correctly propagated. What steps are necessary to increase the cache line sizes, propagate the flag bits to the caches, store/load the flag bits + data, ensure correct communication between caches, etc.?

Can you please let me know the files to be modified to incorporate these.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to figure out how the flag bits are stored when the cache lines (+ flags) are stored to memory. A common approach for such a thing is to store the flags in a separate region of physical memory since storing them inline will disturb cache line alignment.

In terms of files you will need to change, it will unfortunately be quite complicated. Your choice of how to store things in physical memory will require changes to files in the rocket-chip repo itself. You will need to change the files in the uncore repo to pass around these larger cache lines as well as store them in the L2 (if you are using an L2). You will also need to change files within the rocket repo both to set up the interface the processor sees to the new flags as well as adding support to the L1 caches for them.

Even though lowRISC may be based on an older version, I would recommend looking at the changes they made (commit history) to learn the scope and locations or things to change.